# Why does the item not display when i return it? I am getting the memory placement instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Basically what i am trying to do is display all the items in the expenditures list belonging to the same category then followed by the total of each category and lastly, the overall total. For example:

```
$12.00 Mon, 12 Aug 2019 Food
$15.25 Mon, 12 Aug 2019 Food
Total for Food = $27.25
$8.40 Wed, 14 Aug 2019 Drinks
Total for Drinks = $8.40
$33.00 Tue, 13 Aug 2019 Entertainment
Total for Entertainment = $33.00
Overall Total = $178.55
```

```
class ExpenditureList:
    _types = ['Food','Entertainment', 'Drinks']
    def __init__(self):
        self._expenditures = []

    @classmethod
    def ExpenditureTypes(cls):
        return cls._types

    def __str__(self):
        exp = {}
        temp = None
        for types in ExpenditureList._types:
            exp[types] = {'item': []}
            exp[types]['Amount'] = []
        for item in self._expenditures:
            if item._type == ExpenditureList._types[0]:
                exp[item._type]['item'].append(item)
                exp[item._type]['Amount'].append(item._amount)
            elif item._type == ExpenditureList._types[1]:
                exp[item._type]['item'].append(item)
                exp[item._type]['Amount'].append(item._amount)
            elif item._type == ExpenditureList._types[2]:
                exp[item._type]['item'].append(item)
                exp[item._type]['Amount'].append(item._amount)
        for k,v in exp.items():
            if temp == None:
                temp = f"{v['item']}\n"
            else:
                temp = temp + f"{v['item']}\n"
        return temp
```

Some changes were made based on previous comments

Comment: Please paste the error traceback, it tells you EXACTLY what line caused the issue as well as the lines the lead up to the issue.

Comment: `__str__()` shouldn't be printing anything, its job is to return a string version of the object (which the caller might choose to print, or might choose to do something else entirely).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is these two lines (Plus several other spots):

```
exp[types] = []
exp[types]['Amount'] = []
```

Minimal example to cause the error:

```
exp = {}
exp['test'] = []
# exp = {'test': []}
exp['test']['Amount'] = [] # Amount throws an error because exp['test'] is a list.
```

I think you meant to do:

```
exp[types] = {}
exp[types]['Amount'] = []
```

But then your other logic is confusing:

```
# Here you assume exp[item._type] is of type list because you use append on it
exp[item._type].append(item)

# But here you assume exp[item._type] is of type dict because you call ['Amount'] on it...
exp[item._type]['Amount'].append(item._amount)
```